# Django not reading all columns from table

Tags: python, mysql, django

This is a strange one. Maybe I missed it but I have search through all Django documentation and SF but could not find an answer for this. I have a table with about 30 columns. The table looks like this...

```
Class Customer (models.Model):
    customer_id = models.AutoField(primary_key=True)
    first_name = models.CharField(max_length=35)
    last_name = models.CharField(max_length=35)
    middle_initial = models.CharField(max_length=2)
    mail_addr1 = models.CharField(max_length=50)
    mail_addr2 = models.CharField(max_length=50)
    mail_city
    mail_state
    mail_zip
    bill_addr1
    bill_addr2
    ...
    ...
    active_yn = models.ForeignKey('Status', models.DO_NOTHING) # <-- This one
    ...
    ...
    home
    mobile
```

The offending field is "active_yn". Django keeps spitting out an error saying that it is now a valid field. 
Here's the things I am sure of:

1. The table definitely have this field in the correct DB, schema, table, etc
2. It is not the last field on the table.
3. inspectdb for this table is also missing this field.
4. I drop and re-add this column and it is still not showing.
5. The field is a TINYINT(3) - referencing a table Django recognized.
6. I am using MySQL

I have been trying to debug this for days now. Any ideas?

Comment: missing on_delete?

Comment: What is the name of the column in the database?

Comment: log in tinto he dbshell using `python manage.py dbshell` and tell us the output of `desc <table_name>;`

Comment: Name in db is "active_yn".

Comment: I cannot run dbshell ... CommandError: You appear not to have the 'mysql' program installed or on your path.

Comment: Where is the 'status' model defined? In the same app ? Why doesn't it start with a capital S ?

Comment: You say the column exists in the database. So I guess this is a legacy database that is not managed by django. In which case the inner `Meta` class is supposed to define `managed = False`. Among other things you have to take care about when using a legacy database.

Comment: The "status" model is defined in the same app. It is with a capital "S", I make a type in the questions. And I have managed set to False.

Answer (score 0):

Thank you all for helping. I found the issue. The problem is on the DB side. I am using root user connecting directly to the DB. I have the settings file connecting with a different user with tables and fields granted to it. This table has this one field not in the grant to this user (Not my doing... urgh). Anyway, once I added this field, everything works as expected.

I appreciate all your help. Hopefully the next guy will find this useful.

Cheers!